# Animate ToggleButton in ListView without having animation flicker on toggle?

Tags: java, android, listview, animation

So I have a ListView that has a bunch of togglebuttons in it, on those togglebuttons I have an animation for it to change color on toggle, but I also have it set to change color depending on whether data says it should be toggled or not (so that when I scroll up/down the togglebutton is the right color), the problem is when I tap the togglebutton, the animation starts, but getView is called again and so shortly after the animation starts to transition between the colors, it flickers the color to the fully toggled state for a few milliseconds then reverts back to animated value.

How can I keep it functioning how it does but also removing the flicker when toggled by the user? I'd have a video but the flicker is too fast for the screen recorder to capture it.

Here's my adapter for the ListView responsible for all of this:

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View ListItem = convertView;
        Holder holder;
        final dieties diety = data[position];
//        Log.d(TAG, position + " - pos. ");


        if (ListItem == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            ListItem = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new Holder();
            holder.banner = (ImageView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.dietyBanner);
            holder.website = (Button) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.dietyWebsite);
            holder.active = (ToggleButton) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.isActiveButtonToggle);
            holder.highlight =  (ImageView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.highlight);
            holder.title = (TextView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
//            holder.description = (TextView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.dietyDesc);
//            holder.background = (RelativeLayout) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.listItemBG);
//            holder.highlight2 = (ImageView) ListItem.findViewById(R.id.highlight2);


            View.OnClickListener holderListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    WebView webView = (WebView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.webView);
                    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    webView.loadUrl(diety.url);
                }
            };
            holder.website.setOnClickListener(holderListener);


            ListItem.setTag(holder);



        } else {
            holder = (Holder) ListItem.getTag();
        }


        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener ToggleButtonListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
//                int position = (int) buttonView.getParent().getT();
//                dieties diety = data[position];
                diety.active = isChecked;
                SharedPreferences sharedPref = ((Activity) context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefeditor = sharedPref.edit();
                prefeditor.putBoolean(Integer.toString(diety.id), isChecked);
                prefeditor.apply();
                Log.d(TAG, diety.id + " changed to " + diety.active);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                TextView dietyActiveCount = (TextView) ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.dietySelectedCounter);


                final CompoundButton Button = buttonView;
                final RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) ((ViewGroup) Button.getParent()).getParent();


                int startColor = isChecked ? Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a") : Color.parseColor("#2e7d32");
                int endColor = isChecked ? Color.parseColor("#2e7d32") : Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a");
                ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), startColor, endColor);
                colorAnimation.setDuration(100);
                colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {

                        ImageView sideThing1 = (ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.highlight);
//                            ImageView sideThing2 = (ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.highlight2);
                        sideThing1.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
//                            sideThing2.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                        Button.setBackgroundColor((int) animation.getAnimatedValue());

                    }
                });
                colorAnimation.start();
                calcCounter();
                if (currentlyActive == 1){
                    dietyActiveCount.setText("1 diety Selected" );
                } else {
                    dietyActiveCount.setText(currentlyActive + " dieties Selected" );
                }

            }
        };
        holder.active.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ToggleButtonListener);
        Log.d(TAG, diety.id + "");



        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ((Activity) context).getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        diety.active = sharedPref.getBoolean(Integer.toString(diety.id), false);
        holder.active.setOnCheckedChangeListener (null);
        holder.active.setChecked (diety.active);
        if (diety.active) {
            holder.active.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e7d32"));
            holder.highlight.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e7d32"));
//           holder.highlight2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2e7d32"));


        } else {
            holder.active.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a"));
            holder.highlight.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a"));
//           holder.highlight2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ce5a5a"));
        }
        holder.active.setOnCheckedChangeListener (ToggleButtonListener);



        holder.banner.setImageResource(diety.banner);
//        holder.description.setText(diety.description);
        holder.banner.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#616161"));
//        holder.description.setText(diety.url);
        holder.title.setText(diety.title);

        return ListItem;

    }
    static class Holder {

        TextView title;
        ImageView banner;
        Button website;
        ToggleButton active;
        ImageView highlight;



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was calling notifyDataSetChanged wrongly, in the OnCheckedChangeListener which refreshed the whole ListView everytime I pressed it, triggering that if statement. Removing notifyDataSetChanged fixed it.